# Redirect to Action with complex model as parameter that has an array of string property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm facing an problem, I have google and I didn't find how to solve.

I have these two Action

```
    public ActionResult ActionA(DTOA dtoA)
    {
       .....
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActionB(DTOB dtoB)
    {
        DTOA dto = new DTOA();
        dto.ArraOfStringA = dtoB.ArraOfStringB;
        dto.Id = dtoB.Id;


        return RedirectToAction("ActionA", dto);
    }
```

the models

```
public class DTOA
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string[] ArraOfStringA { get; set; }

}

public class DTOB
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string[] ArraOfStringB { get; set; }

}
```

so the situation is

When I post to ActionB, the array of string of dtoB parameter is populated with 2 itens. "1" and "2"

but when this action Redirect to ActionA, dtoA parameter is populated with 1 itens. "System.String[]".

If I type in browser "domain/controler/ActionA?ArraOfStringA=1&ArraOfStringA=2"

the dtoA parameter is populated with two itens. "1" and "2" ( the expected behavior)

So, how can I redirect to ActionA passing an complex model with an property of array os string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to consider using `TempData` to store the model when transferring between two actions rather than using route parameters if the model is complex.

```
public ActionResult ActionA()
{
   var dto = TempData["model"] as DTOA;

   ...
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionB(DTOB dtoB)
{
    DTOA dto = new DTOA();
    dto.ArraOfStringA = dtoB.ArraOfStringB;
    dto.Id = dtoB.Id;

    TempData["model"] = dto;

    return RedirectToAction("ActionA");
}
```

Comment: really? Do you think that is a bad approach Make and Redirect("domain/controller/ActionA?ArrayOfStringA=1&ArrayOfStringA=2")

Comment: On one hand I agree with the spirit of using tempdata ti move on, on the other hand I question why this should be so difficult. I understand how mapping models between View and Controller can be difficult, but in this case, it should be as simple as calling a signed method.

Comment: @DaveA - my concern would be the length of the url for an arbitrary length array of strings as a model. There are possibly many other ways to do it; possibly not even a need to do a redirect but without more information that's hard to say.